# Can't save Fable - The Journey?

Tags: technical-issues, fable-the-journey

I do not have Xbox Live as our village has poor internet. I just bought Fable, but I don't seem to be able to save. Am I able to save?

Answer (score 2):

The game auto-saves for you at specific points while playing. I do not think that you can manually save at other times.